# Add elements up to your intended value

Tags: javascript

I want to add cards from the deck until I get 17 or more if the dealer's total doesn't exceed 17.

Where the error occurs.

When the total value of two cards is not 17 or more, I want to add cards until it becomes 17 or more.
However, with this code, I tried to add cards until I got 17 or more, but I added the same card as the second card (the card that was turned up by pressing the stand button). It's closed.
How do I add cards until I reach 17 or above?

Comment: `while (dealerTotal <17) { drawDealer(cards); }`

Comment: Which code does this apply to?
How do I add a card after pressing the stand button?

Comment: Can you provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ?  I don't know how many people will want to recreate your entire program just to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by your for loop, after calling dealer_3Img in function turnDealer, there is a "break", commented below:

```
function turnDealer(dealerTotal) {
  if(dealerTotal < 17){
    for (let i = dealerTotal; dealerTotal < 17; i++) {
      console.log(i);
      //Get a new card from the array
      var card = deck.pop();
      dealer_3Img(card);
      break //this will exit the loop
    }
  }
}
```

please read the usage of "break": The break statement "jumps out" of a loop.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp

To fix the problem, you can use while as @Aaron suggested, you can use while loop to solve your problem: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_while.asp

Try changing your code to:

```
function turnDealer(dealerTotal) {
  while (dealerTotal < 17) {
    console.log(i);
    //Get a new card from the array
    var card = deck.pop();
    //need to update dealerTotal here, e.g. dealerTotal += card
    dealer_3Img(card);
  }
 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
When I tried with this code, the second card and the third card drawn are the same. Also, if you draw 17 or more, you should stop drawing cards, but until you reach 345, 346, etc., you get a lot of cards from the deck and added them.

Comment: After checking your code again, the logic to update dealerTotal in function turnDealer is missing. I have updated my answer, if you insert the logic to update dealerTotal at the place at the line I commented, the code should work.

Comment: I updated dealerTotal, but it may not be 17 or higher. Also, the card added to the third card has drawn the same card as the second card.

Comment: I would suggest breaking the problem into few smaller problems: 1 if dealerTotal is updated within the while loop, the value of dealerTotal should keep updating until it becomes 17 or higher. You can check the log output to ensure it. 2 deck.pop() should draw a different card each time, you can also log the value of deck.pop() to ensure it.

Comment: I searched about it. Why is it added until it exceeds 17 even though it is set to while (dealerTotal <17)?
And
I want to add a third card from deck using pop. pop gets the elements of the array from the back. At this point, I already got two cards by cards.slice (50) ;, so I want to get elements other than these two cards. However, the second and third sheets will be the same

Comment: The same card problem was caused by cards.slice. slice returns last two cards to you but it does not take away those two cards from the deck array while deck.pop() does. See the usage of slice here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp. If you change cards.slice to deck.pop(), it will remove the drawn card from deck and the same card problem should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me but I don't play cards much.. I'm not sure if each card has a different `dealerTotal` so my example is treating value 17 as 17 cards

```js
// If the dealer does not exceed 17, add cards until it exceeds 17.
function turnDealer (dealerTotal) {
    var card = deck.pop()
    var cardValue=1 //if cardValue is ever not 1, set it to whatever(since idk)
    if (dealerTotal <17) {return turnDealer(dealerTotal+cardValue)}
    return true //it has finished selecting
    //usage: turnDealer(1) would make it take 17 cards, turnDealer(0) would make it take 18, turnDealer(2) would make it take 16 and so on
}
```